# shrinking font/text box within a shape using VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to shrink the text box when ever it overflows or touches boundaries of shape it is within. So that, it fits into the shape ( shapes like rectangle, square etc ). It will be more helpful if this can be done across whole presentation in all slides. Please spread beam of hope!

[image: Image of text overlapping the boxes]

As shown in the picture below, I would like to manipulate text " climate changes " to look like "climate" in upper box.

Answer (score 1):

**It is a simple code:**

```
oShp.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
```

where Oshp is the Shape in PPT

---

**Looping through all shapes in Slide 1**

```
Sub ResizeText()

Dim shp As Shape

    For Each oShp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes

    oShp.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape

    Next


End Sub
```

[Link to Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35887019/5720144)

Answer (score 0):

A text box is never "within" a shape. They are separate objects that are stacked on top of each other. Please see my answer to your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146579/moving-text-text-box-within-a-shape-using-vba-in-powerpoint) for better ways to handle this type of formatting.